# Tree is undefined: Angular update schematics in a NX workspace

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I created an Angular update schematic to update outdated variables to newer ones. However, when I ran the `nx migrate` and `nx migrate --run-migrations` commands in the NX workspace, I received a message saying that no changes were made.

```
import { Rule, SchematicContext, Tree, UpdateRecorder } from '@angular-devkit/schematics';

export default function (): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    tree.visit((path: string, entry) => {
      if (!path.endsWith('.scss') && !path.endsWith('.css')) {
        return;
      }

      const content = entry?.content.toString('utf-8');
      let updatedContent = content;

      const variableMappings = {
        'old': 'new',
      };

      for (const [oldName, newName] of Object.entries(variableMappings)) {
        updatedContent = updatedContent.replace(oldName, newName);
      }

      if (updatedContent !== content) {
        const recorder: UpdateRecorder = tree.beginUpdate(path);
        recorder.remove(0, content.length);
        recorder.insertLeft(0, updatedContent);
        tree.commitUpdate(recorder);
      }
    });

    return tree;
  };
}
```

To troubleshoot the issue, I added a `console.log(tree)` to my code, but it returned an error message stating that the `Tree is undefined`. I also included missing tsconfig file with the script. However, the documentation on this subject is quite inadequate, and I am unsure of how to approach this issue despite following the Angular guide [Schematics for Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/schematics-for-libraries).